# Issues caused in unrelated files when using #import to add msado28.tlb library

Tags: c++, visual-c++, import, compiler-errors, ado

Im having issues adding the MS ADO type libraries into a large established MFC C++ project. Im using MS VS2015 for this project and the import directive im using is as follows:

`#import "C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado\msado28.tlb" rename_namespace("ADO_CG") rename("EOF","EndOfFile")`

Originally I made a blank test project to create basic functionality and it was working great. I built up my classes and then moved them into the main project, this is when the errors started happening. Im unable to build the project due to several errors reporting from "comip.h" which is not a file ive touched. The errors are as follows:

```
    syntax error: missing ')' before 'constant'                           Line 136
    syntax error: missing ')' before 'constant'                           Line 136
    syntax error: 'constant'                                              Line 141
    syntax error: ')'                                                     Line 141
    unexpected token(s) preceding ':'; skipping apparent function body    Line 141
    unexpected end-of-file found                                          Line 931
```

So far ive tried moving the import before any other #includes, targeting different windows versions with the project, messing with several project settings, trying the import in other projects, all yeilding no solution. Im totally at a loss why three other projects ive tried this in work completely fine yet this one refuses to build. If anyone knows why that would be great but at this point any info that would help narrow this down would be appreciated.

Additional info: the header files are being generated correctly for the type library and it is being correctly recognised within the code, its just these other errors being generated that are the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue. Turns out it was an issue with #include ordering in the larger code base which was causing the import to be run mutiple times even from places like stdafk. After some re-organising its all working fine.